# How can we find some radius of circle so $-x\arctan(x)+0.2x-y\arctan(y)+0.9y=0$ will be fully inside this circle?

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, implicit-function

If he have this region 
$$
\begin{align}
\ -x\arctan(x)+0.2x-y\arctan(y)+0.9y=0\\
\end{align}
$$
How can we find some $R$ (maybe minimum) so this region will fully inside this circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$.

In WolframAlpha I've found for example $(x-0.2/2)^2+(y-0.9/2)^2=0.8$ so $R=\sqrt0.8$ fits but have no idea how to prove that and how to find minimum radius.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There will be hardly an exact solution to find the minimal radius. If you want to find the maximal and minimal height of the curve, differentiate in respect to $x$, set $y'=0$ and you'll get
$$\arctan(x)+\frac{x}{1+x^2}+0.2=0.$$
From here you'll find only a numerical approximation of the solutions.

Comment: But what about not minimal radius? I don't need minimal radius for my problem. Can we just find some radius without numerical approximation and be sure that region will be inside this circle?

Comment: Well, obviously you've found one.

Comment: Yes, but it's not proved, I've found it only by attempt, can we make some simple estimation which will show that it's correct?